# Unable to delete gmail contacts group android

Tags: android, gmail, synchronization, android-contacts

I've been trying to delete all the contact group using this code

```
private void deletaAllInGroup(Context context, long groupId)
           throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();         
    values.put(ContactsContract.Groups._ID, groupId);
    getContentResolver().delete(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,values.toString(),null);
        }
```

it is successfully deleting those group which are phone groups but this code is not deleting the gmail contact group how to do that ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem like this way

```
ArrayList<GroupNameDetails> stateList = new ArrayList<GroupNameDetails>();
      final String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] 
                {
                    ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,   ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE//this line will do the trick
                };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, GROUP_PROJECTION, null,
                    null, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String accountname=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), accountname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// and it will display group type
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID));
                Log.v("Test", id);
                //ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME

                String gTitle = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE)));
                if(favGroupName.contains(gTitle)==false)
                {
                favGroupId.add(id);
                favGroupName.add(gTitle);

                GroupNameDetails _states = new GroupNameDetails(Long.parseLong(id),gTitle, false);
                stateList.add(_states);
                }
                Log.v("Test", gTitle);
                if (gTitle.contains("Favorite_")) {
                    gTitle = "Favorites";

                }

            }
```